# What are the implications of blocking SMB traffic laterally between servers?

Tags: networking, firewall, active-directory, smb, netbios

I want to only allow SMB and NBT traffic from servers in the data center to the Domain Controller. I would then like to block any other lateral SMB and NBT traffic.

This is done for security reasons.

What are the implications, will I break something in the network?

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean outgoing traffic only while incoming SMB remain enabled? Then it should not harm.